# choosing random twitter:image while sharing

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter tweet button for sharing website info with large image and some description. i want to change the image randomly for user to user when he visit our website. for the i have used rand(1,7) function in metatag as mentioned below.

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/tweet-images/super-hero/images/image-(<?php echo rand(1,7); ?>).jpg">
```

but after sharing its taking always same image which i wrong. so how to change metatag image randomly while tweeting.